# Does the adjective honey-tongued carry a positive meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context, adjectives

I know honey-tongued can be used to describe a person such as businessman or a politician who is not sincere and persuasive trying to lobby ideas. Can it also be used to describe people who are good at praising others in sweet words?  Are there authentic ways to describe somebody who is sweet and good at talking nice to others, for example, a girl tells a boys that even she never met him before, she can tell from his well-worded speech he must be a modest and hansom boy, the boy goes blushed since he feels so happy being praised in such a nice way.

Comment: Honey-Tongued refers strictly to the tongue.  You will notice it does not mention the personality or motives of the honey-tongue's owner.  That's because the honey does not apply  to additional traits.  If the girl in your example is sincere in her praise, you might also include her personality or nature in your description.  *She is sweet girl who always has such nice things to say.*  The honey here applies to more than just one thing.

Comment: Surely you can tell that someone is handsome by looking at them, not from their speech!

Comment: a "hansom boy" - can he be trusted in a cab?

Comment: Without trying to guess the intentions of the speaker, let me point out that someone who says "honey-tongued" is likely not think about "well-worded speech", but rather more exclusively how the speaker is "sweet".   In other words, "honey-tongued" refers to the *positive way in which the words of the described speaker may be received* more than it refers to the *skill of that speaker*.   It most often implies **flattery** - but the person describing the speaker very likely thinks that the speaker described is *intentionally being kind*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. These days, *honey-tongued* can have that more positive meaning, although it almost always still carries at least a hint of suspicion of there being *some* degree of ulterior motive on the part of the person in question. (In the past, however, *honey-tongued* could refer to a writer or speaker's skill with words in terms of aesthetics.)

But as to an alternative that ensures there is no hint of the shady politician's attempt to manipulate, I can't come up with anything that really captures it precisely. I'd certainly agree with Colin's "appreciative". Other options include one that you yourself mentioned, "sweet"; and "kind". For example, were someone to say to me:

> You are a man of great courage and compassion, with a heart both lionesque and tender; of a lofty wisdom rarely seen these forlorn days; of such masculine beauty that women would dash themselves on the rocks of your visage; and of such wit and charm that the very angels fall silent and become rapt at your every word.

I might respond,

> Thank you. You are very **kind**.

Or

> Well thanks. That is very **sweet** of you.

Or even

> OK, OK, cut the crap ye big chancer. I'm not falling for that again. What are you after this time? And what's a visage anyway?

Answer (score -1):

No. I would always interpret *honey-tongued* as meaning that the sweetness extends only to the tongue, and not to the person.

A word for the kind of person you are describing would be *appreciative*.